# Inconsistent RegEx whitespace cleanup

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have the following little whitespace clean up function and while it works perfectly when losing focus by tabbing to the next tabindex, if I simply lose focus by clicking off the element that is currently receiving focus and re-examine the clean up is done EXCEPT for the [ \t]+$ at the end of the "string"

```
function cleanUpYourAct(){
$(':text').each(function(index){    
var messy = $(this).val();
var clean = messy.replace(/\s+/g," ");
var trimmed = clean.replace(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/,"");
$(this).val(trimmed);   
});
}

$(':text').blur(cleanUpYourAct);
```

Any ideas?  Maybe regex set I bunched together is garbage?

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not doing a global replace on the second regex, so if there is whitespace at the beginning you're not also replacing whitespace at the end:

```
var trimmed = clean.replace(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/g,"");
```

**EDIT:**

You might also think about performing this action on just the element that is the event target.

Something like:

```
function cleanUpYourAct () {
  var messy = $(this).val()
    , clean = messy.replace(/\s+/g, " ")
    , trimmed = clean.replace(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/g, "")
  $(this).val(trimmed)
}
```

Comment: You went above and beyond with this answer, Thom.  I think you may be a GOD!